# How to put an input listing to fill both columns in a two column format without the end of it getting cut off from the page?

Tags: listings, overleaf, lstdefinestyle

I need to add a bunch of code to show the entire CPP file for the problem that I gave participants to solve but the code keeps cutting off the page no matter what style I define it as. I am using overleaf and was asked to format my paper with this [template](http://asplos-conference.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/asplos23-templates-fall.zip). Here is a MWE with the template here. I just used some dummy code from the std::mutex example because I wanted a long portion of code to be in the document.

```
\documentclass[pageno]{jpaper}

\newcommand{\asplossubmissionnumber}{XXX}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}


\lstdefinestyle{fullStyle}{%
%   framerule=1pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible
}



\begin{document}

\title{
Some Title is here}

\date{}
\maketitle



\section{Some section}
\lipsum[50]

\section{Another section}
\lipsum[50]

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,style=fullStyle, captionpos=b, caption=Testing Listing Placement,float=*]
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
 
struct Employee {
    Employee(std::string id) : id(id) {}
    std::string id;
    std::vector<std::string> lunch_partners;
    std::mutex m;
    std::string output() const
    {
        std::string ret = "Employee " + id + " has lunch partners: ";
        for( const auto& partner : lunch_partners )
            ret += partner + " ";
        return ret;
    }
};
 
void send_mail(Employee &, Employee &)
{
    // simulate a time-consuming messaging operation
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
 
void assign_lunch_partner(Employee &e1, Employee &e2)
{
    static std::mutex io_mutex;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);
        std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " are waiting for locks" << std::endl;
    }
 
    // use std::lock to acquire two locks without worrying about 
    // other calls to assign_lunch_partner deadlocking us
    {
        std::lock(e1.m, e2.m);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::adopt_lock);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::adopt_lock);
// Equivalent code (if unique_locks are needed, e.g. for condition variables)
//        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::defer_lock);
//        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::defer_lock);
//        std::lock(lk1, lk2);
// Superior solution available in C++17
//        std::scoped_lock lk(e1.m, e2.m);
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);
            std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " got locks" << std::endl;
        }
        e1.lunch_partners.push_back(e2.id);
        e2.lunch_partners.push_back(e1.id);
    }
    send_mail(e1, e2);
    send_mail(e2, e1);
}
 
int main()
{
    Employee alice("alice"), bob("bob"), christina("christina"), dave("dave");
 
    // assign in parallel threads because mailing users about lunch assignments
    // takes a long time
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(alice), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(alice));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(dave), std::ref(bob));
 
    for (auto &thread : threads) thread.join();
    std::cout << alice.output() << '\n'  << bob.output() << '\n'
              << christina.output() << '\n' << dave.output() << '\n';
              
    // assign in parallel threads because mailing users about lunch assignments
    // takes a long time
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(alice), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(alice));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(dave), std::ref(bob));
}
\end{lstlisting}


\section{Another section Goes Here}
\lipsum[50]

\section{Acknowledgements}
Thanks to people who participated and advised
on certain things

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}



\end{document}
```

How can I get this code to be formatted correctly as a listing such that it splits properly into the pages it encompasses and does not just get cut off when the content does not fit the page? I have been looking at the listing [docs](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing) for a few days and nothing seems to prevent that from cutting off. Unfortunately, the `multicol` solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8177/listing-over-two-columns-how-to-page-break) did not work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to use `tcolorbox` together with `listings` and `breakable` libraries.

**Note**: You don't have to worry about breaking code across multiple pages manually. `tcolorbox` does it for us. Unless you have a strong reason, I don't think it is necessary to restrict the code to a single page, irrespective of whether you have multiple columns.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.75in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[breakable,listings]{tcolorbox}


\lstdefinestyle{fullStyle}{%
    %   framerule=1pt,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    language=C++
}



\begin{document}    
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only,breakable,listing options={style=fullStyle}}
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

struct Employee {
    Employee(std::string id) : id(id) {}
    std::string id;
    std::vector<std::string> lunch_partners;
    std::mutex m;
    std::string output() const
    {
        std::string ret = "Employee " + id + " has lunch partners: ";
        for( const auto& partner : lunch_partners )
        ret += partner + " ";
        return ret;
    }
};

void send_mail(Employee &, Employee &)
{
    // simulate a time-consuming messaging operation
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

void assign_lunch_partner(Employee &e1, Employee &e2)
{
    static std::mutex io_mutex;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);
        std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " are waiting for locks" << std::endl;
    }
    
    // use std::lock to acquire two locks without worrying about 
    // other calls to assign_lunch_partner deadlocking us
    {
        std::lock(e1.m, e2.m);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::adopt_lock);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::adopt_lock);
        // Equivalent code (if unique_locks are needed, e.g. for condition variables)
        //        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::defer_lock);
        //        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::defer_lock);
        //        std::lock(lk1, lk2);
        // Superior solution available in C++17
        //        std::scoped_lock lk(e1.m, e2.m);
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);
            std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " got locks" << std::endl;
        }
        e1.lunch_partners.push_back(e2.id);
        e2.lunch_partners.push_back(e1.id);
    }
    send_mail(e1, e2);
    send_mail(e2, e1);
}

int main()
{
    Employee alice("alice"), bob("bob"), christina("christina"), dave("dave");
    
    // assign in parallel threads because mailing users about lunch assignments
    // takes a long time
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(alice), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(alice));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(dave), std::ref(bob));
    
    for (auto &thread : threads) thread.join();
    std::cout << alice.output() << '\n'  << bob.output() << '\n'
    << christina.output() << '\n' << dave.output() << '\n';
    
    // assign in parallel threads because mailing users about lunch assignments
    // takes a long time
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(alice), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(bob));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(christina), std::ref(alice));
    threads.emplace_back(assign_lunch_partner, std::ref(dave), std::ref(bob));
}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for this. I was trying to get all of this into one column that spanned the two-column space. I'm not sure if I am communicating this correctly. It's like when you use the {table*} instead of {table}.